# show_all = False not working with SpeechRecognition 3.9

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm using the following code to transcribe audio files using [this package](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) version 3.9.x, which worked with no issues a year ago. While it produces the desired output, it keeps printing the whole process (all the iterations of transcriptions and their accuracy) even though I have explicitly set `show_all = False`. The output I get is normal, I merely want to stop it from printing the whole process while running. Has anyone else had this issue/found a workaround?

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
    audio_data = r.record(source)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_data,language='ru-RU', show_all=False)
```

Comment: could not find `speech_recognition` with pip. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: I guess this one: https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/

Comment: Yes, my apologies. It is the one @MarcinOrlowski has linked

Comment: thanks, sry (consider I'm tired and not in the mood for deep search ... happens)

Comment: made a test in en-EN with python `3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)]` and `SpeechRecognition 3.10.0` and everything worked fine with no specific verbose output of the processing. Do you have any specific configuration that might activate a debug logger ? can you show what is the unwanted output  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issue on my side with SpeechRecognition 3.10.0.

Issue seems present in 3.9.0, and related to [this pull ticket #651]https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/pull/651) related to [this issue #645](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/645), quoting:

> When calling recognize_google method of speech_recognition it prints the entire JSON response, investigating the problem is on the 917 and 918 lines of speech_recognition_init_.py

## with 3.9.0

```
pip install SpeechRecognition==3.9.0 --force-reinstall

ipython

In [1]: import speech_recognition as sr
   ...:
   ...: r = sr.Recognizer()
   ...: # source: https://www.liveatc.net/recordings.php line:
   ...: # 2023-03-03 10:34:20   Balloon warning KPBI (humorous)     kb4tez 
   ...: # https://forums.liveatc.net/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=16994.0;attach=11640
   ...: filename = r"balloonKPBI2-Twr-Mar-02-2023-2100Z.mp3_converted.wav"
   ...: with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
   ...:     audio_data = r.record(source)
   ...:     text = r.recognize_google(audio_data,language='en-EN', show_all=False)
   ...:
result2:
{   'alternative': [   {   'confidence': 0.9437989,
                           'transcript': 'clear land 10 left frontier by 26 '
                                         '790 times there was a balloon at '
                                         '1200 feet on the final few and '
                                         'frontier sorry Roger Customs Eddie '
                                         'one custom jet 960 3 is with young '
                                         'visual get 963 Tower and my 101 left '
                                         'continue travel be holding a '
                                         'position used caution balloons '
                                         'reported on spinal 1200 feet so '
                                         'great the Chinese variety again all '
                                         'right 963'},
                       {   'transcript': 'clear land 10 left frontier by 26 '
                                         '790 times there was a balloon at '
                                         '1200 feet on the final few and '
                                         'frontier sorry Roger Customs Eddie '
                                         'one custom jet 960 3 is with young '
                                         'visual get 963 Tower and my 101 left '
                                         'continue travel be holding a '
                                         'position used caution balloons '
                                         'reported on spinal 1200 feet so '
                                         'great the Chinese variety again '
                                         'alright 963'},
                       {   'transcript': 'clear land 10 left frontier by 26 '
                                         '790 times there was a balloon at '
                                         '1200 feet on the final few and '
                                         'frontier sorry custom said he won '
                                         'custom jet 960 3 is with young '
                                         'visual get 963 Tower and my 101 left '
                                         'continue travel be holding a '
                                         'position used caution balloons '
                                         'reported on spinal 1200 feet so '
                                         'great the Chinese variety again all '
                                         'right 963'},
                       {   'transcript': 'clear land 10 left frontier by 26 '
                                         '790 times there was a balloon at '
                                         '1200 feet on the final few and '
                                         'frontier sorry Roger Customs Eddy '
                                         'one custom jet 960 3 is with young '
                                         'visual get 963 Tower and my 101 left '
                                         'continue travel be holding a '
                                         'position used caution balloons '
                                         'reported on spinal 1200 feet so '
                                         'great the Chinese variety again all '
                                         'right 963'},
                       {   'transcript': 'clear land 10 left frontier by 26 '
                                         '790 times there was a balloon at '
                                         '1200 feet on the final few and '
                                         'frontier sorry Roger Customs Eddie '
                                         'one custom jet 960 3 is with young '
                                         'visual get 963 Tower and my 101 left '
                                         'continue travel be holding a '
                                         'position used caution balloons '
                                         'reported on spinal 1,200 feet so '
                                         'great the Chinese variety again all '
                                         'right 963'}],
    'final': True}

In [2]: sr.__version__
Out[2]: '3.9.0'
In [3]: import sys

In [4]: sys.version
Out[4]: '3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

## with 3.10.0

```
pip install SpeechRecognition==3.9.0 --force-reinstall

ipython

In [1]: import speech_recognition as sr
   ...:
   ...: r = sr.Recognizer()
   ...: # source: https://www.liveatc.net/recordings.php line:
   ...: # 2023-03-03 10:34:20   Balloon warning KPBI (humorous)     kb4tez 
   ...: # https://forums.liveatc.net/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=16994.0;attach=11640
   ...: filename = r"balloonKPBI2-Twr-Mar-02-2023-2100Z.mp3_converted.wav"
   ...: with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
   ...:     audio_data = r.record(source)
   ...:     text = r.recognize_google(audio_data,language='en-EN', show_all=False)
   ...:

In [2]: text
Out[2]: 'clear land 10 left frontier by 26 790 times there was a balloon at 1200 feet on the final few and frontier sorry Roger Customs Eddie one custom jet 960 3 is with young visual get 963 Tower and my 101 left continue travel be holding a position used caution balloons reported on spinal 1200 feet so great the Chinese variety again all right 963'

In [3]: len(text)
Out[3]: 342

In [4]: sr.__version__
Out[4]: '3.10.0'

In [5]: import sys

In [6]: sys.version
Out[6]: '3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

Comment: Ah yes. I think it was a bug on the 3.9 version. As soon as I updated to 3.10 this disappeared. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for voting and confirmation. I completed my answer to further confirm the behavior.